# How to handle timezones in FCM

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm in the process of developing an API backend using Django Rest Framework. Currently, I have a requirement to send notifications to mobile devices, which I've implemented using FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging). However, I'm facing an issue: I need to send notifications at specific times according to different timezones, and I have access to the timezones of each user. I'm considering implementing a cron job to check if the designated time has arrived. Is this approach ideal for my requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Using a cron job to periodically check and send notifications based on specific times in different timezones is a viable approach, but it might not be the most efficient and scalable solution, especially if you have a large number of users with different timezones. Let me explain the pros and cons of this approach and suggest an alternative approach that might be more suitable for your requirements.

**Cron Job Approach:**

**Pros:**

- Simple to implement, especially if you're already familiar with cron
  jobs.
- Can work well for a relatively small number of users and
  notifications.
- Doesn't require real-time processing.

**Cons:**

- Resource-intensive: If you have a large number of users, each with their own timezone and notification time, the cron job might need to run very frequently, consuming server resources.
- Latency: Notifications might not be delivered at the exact time specified due to the periodic nature of cron jobs.
- Not very scalable: As the number of users and notifications increases, managing and scaling cron jobs becomes complex.

**Alternate Approach:**

Instead of relying on a cron job, you might consider a more event-driven approach using a message queue system. Here's how it could work:

**Pros:**

- Scalability: This approach can handle a large number of users and notifications more efficiently as it's event-driven.
- Accuracy: Notifications can be sent at the exact user-specified time, without relying on periodic checks.
- Reduced resource usage: You won't need to run resource-intensive cron jobs frequently.

**Cons:**

- Slightly more complex to set up compared to a simple cron job.

Comment: can i use amazon sqs for this?

Comment: Amazon SQS is a robust and scalable solution for implementing a message queue system to handle notification scheduling based on different timezones. It offers many advantages over the cron job approach and is well-suited for cloud-based applications, especially if you're already using AWS services. But it can be costly if you go above free tier.

Comment: The DelaySeconds parameter in Amazon SQS is limited to a maximum value of 900 seconds (15 minutes). In the context of scheduling future notifications, i might need a different approach.

Comment: If that's the case you can add a custom logic at the backend and check which notifications need to sent and push them into queue.

Comment: did you use chatgpt or any similar AI at all to write any part of this answer?